# Redirect with session from FormRequest Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I was performing validation inside controller, and from there I can return messages through the session.

```
return redirect()->back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->with([
                'editModal' => 'editModal',
                'msg'       => $msg
            ]);
```

Then, I tried using `FormRequest` in Laravel. This `FormRequest` works, but I want to send some data with session if validation is failed. But I can not find a way to do this. I can send messages using `$validator->errors()->add` but is there a way to send a message through session the same way I used `with()` in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom error in validators error

```
$validator->errors()->add('editModal', 'editModal');
$validator->errors()->add('msg', $msg);
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
```

in your blade

```
@if($errors->any())
 <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The `FormRequest::failedValidation()` method throws an instance of [`\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php) to indicate a validation failure.

There are two methods in `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler` that deal with building the response for these exceptions. You'll need to override these two methods, [`invalid()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L255) and [`invalidJson()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L269), to include your session data.

These overrides belong in your app's exception handler, found at **app/Exception/Handler.php** and should look something like this:

```
protected function invalid($request, ValidationException $exception)
{
    return redirect($exception->redirectTo ?? url()->previous())
                ->withInput(Arr::except($request->input(), $this->dontFlash))
                ->withErrors($exception->errors(), $exception->errorBag)
                ->with([
                    'editModal' => 'editModal',
                    'msg'       => $msg
                ]);
}

protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception)
{
    return response()
        ->json([
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'errors' => $exception->errors(),
        ], $exception->status)
        ->with([
            'editModal' => 'editModal',
            'msg'       => $msg
        ]);

}
```

Comment: unfortunately `getResponse()` will return `null` since there was no `$response` passed as the second arg to the constructor of `ValidationException` ... you can build a response object and pass it in though

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. Trying another approach.

Comment: if you assign a Response, that is what gets returned by the Exception Handler, the Handler does not build a Response for you now ...  you will need the Response to be a redirect response to where you want it to go with the `withInput(...)->withErrors(...)` calls; you need to build the complete response that will be returned ... fun fun :)

Comment: LOL unless your name's Taylor I'm not blaming you. Looks like you're right, all the redirection and error stuff gets done in [`Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L237) for whatever reason. OP's probably better off just keeping it in the controller at this point. Will take a look in the morning.

Comment: LOL, I think i will use your suggestion: keeping it in the controller.

Comment: @tokmbo one more edit; since building the request is done in the exception handler, that's the override you need to make.

Answer (score 1):

After spending my times, I found a way to send message through session. Just add this function on `FormRequest` class you use.

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->with([ //these are my messages
            'editModal' => 'editModal',
            'msg'       => $this->input()
        ]);
}
```

Don't forget to `use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;`

Comment: This does not return a proper HTTP status code, nor will it include the old values.

Comment: I used session in my case, but I tried and it includes old values too.

Edit: Oops, my wrong. It will cause an error. This will work with session only.